# Pycharm cannot display methods suggestion on Robot files from my custom library

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, robotframework

I have a library with name Service.py contains:

```
def set_up(self, nameItem="", type=""):
 return "set up is starting..."
```

In my Pycharm project, I created a robot file contains:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Service WITH NAME ServiceKeywords
Suit Setup  ServiceKeywords.Set Up "Item Name" "Wood"
```

This test case works well, but I must type this code manually when I entered "Ser" and pressed "Ctrl + Space", not any suggestion here.
When I typed "ServiceKeywords." and pressed "Ctrl + Space", the same thing occurred.

Can Pycharm autocomplete for robot file which call method from a python library?

Comment: Do you use any pycharm plugin for RF?

Comment: yeah, I use intelibot plugin, pycharm 2016.3.3, python 2.7.12

Comment: Do you follow this? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-names

Comment: Yah, my test case can be executed successfully, but no suggestion from pycharm for my custom librariese

Comment: I see! I would say neither Pycharm itself nor any from RF plugins known to me are able to work correctly with Library imported using `WITH NAME` syntax. It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Lib import looks fine,it looks like not supported case by plugin.

I checked with RED ( http://nokia.github.io/RED/ ), we provide content assist when user starts with lib name **although** this does not work in Suite Setup. I have created internal ticket for that.

As an workaround, in RED you can choose how content assist will write down keywords from resources and libs to tests. By default it provides *kwName*,this can be change to provide *libName.kwName* (same with resource) 
from Window->Preferences->Robot Framework->Editor->Content Assist

Comment: Latest RED release 0.7.7 includes your case.